# How should I do to debug into HTMLDocumentParser class(which is in third_party) in chromium code with vs2019?

Tags: chromium, blink

How should I debug into HTMLDocumentParser class which is in `third_party/blink/renderer/core/html/parser/html_document_parser.cc` with vs2019?

When I debug chrome.exe, I put a breakpoint in this file, but it shows me that "the breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chromium uses multi-process architecture as shown [here](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/multi-process-architecture/)
. In your case, you are debugging the browser process.

As soon as the main browser process is launched, Chromium will spawn some renderer processes which renders the page. So you should debug renderer process instead. You have to attach to that specific renderer process to debug it.

To debug renderer process on Windows, you can find instructions [here](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/debugging-on-windows/) and for other platforms [here](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/)